# How to install Golang package locally that's referenced as a github.com address

Tags: docker, go

I have a package that I'm referencing in my Go code as:

```
github.com/apache/pulsar/pulsar-function-go/pf
```

However, I need to include some *local* changes to that library when building a docker image for setting up an integration test.

In my Dockerfile, I've setup GOPATH and GOROOT and PATH like this:

```
ENV GOROOT /usr/local/go
ENV GOPATH /go
ENV PATH /go/bin:$PATH
```

Then, in the Dockerfile, I copy the source code into my Docker image and attempt to install the Go module, like this:

```
COPY target/pulsar-function-go/ /pulsar/dependencies/pulsar-function-go/
RUN cd /pulsar/dependencies/pulsar-function-go/pf && go install .
```

However, when I then try to build a file that references `github.com/apache/pulsar/pulsar-function-go/pf` by running this line:

`RUN go build -o /pulsar/examples/go-examples/exclamationFunc /pulsar/examples/go-examples/exclamationFunc.go`

I get this exception message:

> ---> Running in bb3ec43f7fea
>   examples/go-examples/exclamationFunc.go:24:2: cannot find package
>   "github.com/apache/pulsar/pulsar-function-go/pf" in any of:
>           /usr/local/go/src/github.com/apache/pulsar/pulsar-function-go/pf (from
>   $GOROOT)
>           /go/src/github.com/apache/pulsar/pulsar-function-go/pf (from $GOPATH)

Is there a way to allow me to use a locally installed version of that same package without needing to change the reference in the code that I'm trying to build?

**EDIT Here's everything else I've tried:**

When I run go install in pulsar-function-go, I get:

```
cannot find module for path .
```

When I run go install in pulsar-function-go/pf, I get:

```
examples/go-examples/exclamationFunc.go:24:2: cannot find package "github.com/apache/pulsar/pulsar-function-go/pf" in any of:
        /usr/local/go/src/github.com/apache/pulsar/pulsar-function-go/pf (from $GOROOT)
        /go/src/github.com/apache/pulsar/pulsar-function-go/pf (from $GOPATH)
```

When I try running:

```
RUN go get -t github.com/apache/pulsar/pulsar-function-go/...
```

(although this won’t bring in my local changes, it was just for testing)
I get:

```
# github.com/apache/pulsar/pulsar-function-go/examples/test
/go/src/github.com/apache/pulsar/pulsar-function-go/examples/test/producer.go:30:6: main redeclared in this block
        previous declaration at /go/src/github.com/apache/pulsar/pulsar-function-go/examples/test/consumer.go:30:6
# github.com/apache/pulsar/pulsar-function-go/examples
/go/src/github.com/apache/pulsar/pulsar-function-go/examples/hello.go:32:6: main redeclared in this block
        previous declaration at /go/src/github.com/apache/pulsar/pulsar-function-go/examples/contextFunc.go:36:6
/go/src/github.com/apache/pulsar/pulsar-function-go/examples/inputFunc.go:34:6: main redeclared in this block
        previous declaration at /go/src/github.com/apache/pulsar/pulsar-function-go/examples/hello.go:32:6
/go/src/github.com/apache/pulsar/pulsar-function-go/examples/outputFunc.go:33:6: main redeclared in this block
        previous declaration at /go/src/github.com/apache/pulsar/pulsar-function-go/examples/inputFunc.go:34:6
```

When I try running:

```
RUN go get -t github.com/apache/pulsar/pulsar-function-go
```

I get:

```
package github.com/apache/pulsar/pulsar-function-go: no Go files in /go/src/github.com/apache/pulsar/pulsar-function-go
```

If I try running this to first get some of the dependencies:

```
RUN go get -t github.com/apache/pulsar/pulsar-function-go/pf
```

it succeeds. If I then follow that in my Dockerfile with:

```
# after using Maven plugin to copy files from the pulsar-function-go source directory to target/pulsar-function-go
COPY target/pulsar-function-go/ /go/src/github.com/apache/pulsar/pulsar-function-go
RUN cd /go/src/github.com/apache/pulsar/pulsar-function-go/pf && go install
```

to replace the source code for pulsar-function-go in the docker file with my local code, then when I try to build the binary, like this:

```
RUN go build -o /pulsar/examples/go-examples/exclamationFunc /pulsar/examples/go-examples/exclamationFunc.go
```

I get:

```
/go/src/github.com/apache/pulsar/pulsar-function-go/pb/InstanceCommunication.pb.go:29:2: cannot find package "google.golang.org/grpc" in any of:
        /usr/local/go/src/google.golang.org/grpc (from $GOROOT)
        /go/src/google.golang.org/grpc (from $GOPATH)
/go/src/github.com/apache/pulsar/pulsar-function-go/pb/InstanceCommunication.pb.go:30:2: cannot find package "google.golang.org/grpc/codes" in any of:
        /usr/local/go/src/google.golang.org/grpc/codes (from $GOROOT)
        /go/src/google.golang.org/grpc/codes (from $GOPATH)
/go/src/github.com/apache/pulsar/pulsar-function-go/pb/InstanceCommunication.pb.go:31:2: cannot find package "google.golang.org/grpc/status" in any of:
        /usr/local/go/src/google.golang.org/grpc/status (from $GOROOT)
        /go/src/google.golang.org/grpc/status (from $GOPATH)
12:13
```

The google.golang.org/grpc package is included in the `go.mod` file, which looks like this:

```
module github.com/apache/pulsar/pulsar-function-go
go 1.13
require (
    github.com/apache/pulsar-client-go v0.0.0-20200116214305-4d788d9935ed
    github.com/golang/protobuf v1.3.2
    github.com/sirupsen/logrus v1.4.1
    github.com/stretchr/testify v1.3.0
    golang.org/x/tools v0.0.0-20200119215504-eb0d8dd85bcc // indirect
    google.golang.org/grpc v1.26.0
    gopkg.in/yaml.v2 v2.2.2
)
```

From the answer below, I was told that I can insert a `replace` directive in the Go module to allow us to point to local files when I build the Go binaries for the tests. 
However, I don’t think I’m able to install the module correctly, perhaps due to the way the pulsar-function-go/examples are included in the module.
So, I can't figure out what to set as the `/local/path/to/package` because I can't install the package successfully. (Maybe I'm confused about this too?)

Is there a better way that we could structure the module/code to enable the installation of the local pulsar-function-go module into the test Docker image?

If you want to look at the Go code yourself, see it here: https://github.com/apache/pulsar/tree/master/pulsar-function-go
The Dockerfile is here: https://github.com/apache/pulsar/blob/master/tests/docker-images/latest-version-image/Dockerfile

Comment: Why would someone vote to close this question? Is the answer to this question really that obvious to all other Go developers? I searched for a solution and came up empty.

Comment: was this ever resolved?

Answer (score 3):

Use go modules for your project, and include a `replace` directive in it for the package you're referencing to:

```
replace github.com/apache/pulsar/pulsar-function-go/pf => /local/path/to/package
```

Comment: @devinbost, are you sure about that? The error message indicates otherwise. It shouldn't mention GOPATH in module mode. Module mode is disabled in 1.11 and 1.12 if GOPATH is set. Don't set GOPATH if you want to use modules to avoid confusion.

Comment: @Peter Thanks for the information about GOPATH and Module mode. This is the first I've heard of that. 
Other than that, you're welcome to look for yourself: https://github.com/apache/pulsar/tree/master/pulsar-function-go

Comment: @Peter I updated my post to include a lot more information.